# C++ Client/Nodejs Server send POST binary data

Tags: c++, node.js, curl, libcurl

I have a C++ client and a Nodejs Server. I want to send binary data (an hex string) via POST. I'm struggling trying to understand what's the problem here.
The problem: I get on server a Buffer with **all the same bytes** everytime. No matter what I send.

I guess I do not handle the Buffer on server the right way.
Please note bodyParser.raw usage, I'm not sure about it.
This is the part of the Client sending data:

```
//http POST request
int Remote::postRequest(const char *socket, char *content) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: */*");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, socket);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, content);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);                                                                                    
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the server

```
const app = require('express')(),
app
    .use(bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/octet-stream'}))
    .post('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log('body: ',req.body);
        console.log('binToHex: ',new Buffer(req.body.toString('hex'),'binary'));
        console.log('bin: ', Buffer(req.body,'binary'))
        res.send("ok")  
    }).listen(3000, () => console.info('listening on port 3000..'))
```

That's what the server prints **no matter what I send**

```
body:  <Buffer cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc>
binToHex:  <Buffer 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 ... >
bin:  <Buffer cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc>
```

Comment: How are you calling postRequest?

Comment: the code it's a bit long (not complex) but the end of the day `content` is a simple string. `socket` is IP+port, obiouvsly that's not the problem..